# Navigation Menu Options - drop downs and sticky?

Tags: templating, navigation

I'm new to Craft CMS.

1. It is possible to create a navigation menu with drop down menu items
2. and a sticky menu bar on the desktop view please?

How/where do I do this please? (Using Craft 2.7.10)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both of those are possible in Craft, but this question doesn't really make sense for Craft projects. Craft doesn't care what you put in your frontend template, and it doesn't come with a theme system like WordPress or Drupal. Instead, you are free to create and structure your templates in whatever way you want, and use Craft's API to fetch and display content from the CMS. So basically, everything is possible – it's just a matter of what you can build.

To get started, take a look at the [templating docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html), that's a good place to get comfortable with Twig and start building your templates the way you want them.

You can take a look at the [Navigation](https://plugins.craftcms.com/navigation) plugin, which allows you to create navigation menus in the backend and render them in the frontend. The plugin allows for nested hierarchies of menu items, which is a prerequisite for drop down menus. But it won't help you with styling the menu output, that's something you can do yourself.

If you're using a framework like Bootstrap, you can check if it has a component that fits your requirements – for example, [Bootstrap's navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) will allow you to create sticky navigation bars with dropdowns. You can use the Navigation plugin mentioned above to output the menu's HTML structure as expected by navbar component, this will get you to something usable very quickly.